# Как создать компонент Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, php7, компоненты

Всем привет. Собственно вопрос в заголовке - как создать свой кастомный компонент в Symfony? Обрыл весь сайт, доку по этому поводу не нашел.

Comment: Что значит компонент?

Comment: В симфони есть список готовых компонентов https://symfony.com/components. Мне нужно написать свой кастомный компонент для своего проекта.

Comment: Проблема в том что компонент - это просто библиотека, набор классов, которая подключается в Симфони. Компоненты симфони можно подключать в другие проекты, которые написаны например на чистом пхп, или с использованием каких-то самописных фреймворков (даже можно упороться и в битрикс их подключить). Таким образом, мы приходим к тому что вам надо либо написать какую-то библиотеку в вакууме (тогда это вообще никак не связано с симфони), либо какой-то бандл, который будет юзать классы из компонентов симфони.

Comment: Спасибо. Я до этого только с Yii работал, там целая статья есть https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/747/write-use-a-custom-component-in-yii2-0. Ну вроде этого. В симфони же ни слова как писать, куда складывать. Т.е. получается в папке src можно создать папку components и в нее складывать компоненты. А работать с ними как с обычными классами в php. По структуре будет типа src/components/customcomponents. Правильно я понимаю?

Comment: Я думаю что Вы искали сервисы
[EN](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html)
[RU](https://symfony.com.ua/doc/current/service_container.html)

Comment: Спасибо, но мне не совсем понятна логика. В симфони есть свои компонены, но писать свои нельзя, вместо этого нужно использовать сервисы ?

Comment: Сервисы это те же компоненты и кастомные создаются очень просто

Comment: Если сервисы и компоненты это одно и тоже, какой смысл было вводить два разных названия ? Может все-таки это разные вещи ?

Comment: А для чего вам нужны "компоненты"? Я уверен что сервис решит Вашу проблему, если реализация не помещается в сервис - создайте бандл. Не вижу смысла обсуждать особенности перевода

Comment: Причем тут перевод ? Я и без перевода могу прочитать, не тупее остальных. Я просто хочу разобраться как сделать правильнее. Мне нужно создать по сути тоже самое что уже есть http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form.html Но у меня все проще гораздо, поэтому смысла наследоваться не вижу, чтобы не тащить лишнего. Отсюда возникла идея форкнуть и на его основе сделать свой. Поэтому и возник вопрос о компонентах.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32771495/what-is-the-difference-between-a-bundle-component-and-a-service-in-symfony-fram Тут описано различие компонентов, сервисов, бандлов в симфони. Для вашей задачи можно создать свой бандл и это будет symfony-way

Comment: Большое спасибо :) Хотя жалко конечно, что свои компоненты нельзя. В Yii можно, а в Symfony нельзя, неожиданно однако...